# Post binary file and parameters to Web Services via Oracle APEX 4.2 - HTTP 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: oracle, post, plsql, apex, 400-bad-request

I would like to Post a binary file (and some parameters in URL) to a Web Services via an Oracle Apex 4.2 form.

I'm going to try to post the binary files with a PlSQL function, but I receive this error from the WebServices response:

HTTP 400 Bad Request Error

I've checked the URL and seems to be well-formed: if I post the request without the file, work fine.. but I need to post the file too...

This is my code:

```
FUNCTION POST(URL VARCHAR2, DATA_IN BLOB, HTTPS BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE) RETURN CLOB IS

  BEGIN

   DECLARE

    DATA_OUT  CLOB;
    PIECE     VARCHAR2(4000);
    --AMT       PLS_INTEGER := 4000;
    --POS       PLS_INTEGER := 1;
    HTTP_REQ  UTL_HTTP.REQ;
    HTTP_RESP UTL_HTTP.RESP;

    BUFFER     RAW(32767);
    AMOUNT     PLS_INTEGER := 4000;     
    REQ_LENGTH INT:=0;
    OFFSET     INT:=1;     


    -- Variables to handle the web service response
    L_RESPONSE                          CLOB;
    L_BUFFER                            VARCHAR2(4000);
 
    request_contest   utl_http.request_context_key;
 

   BEGIN
 

     IF HTTPS THEN
        --UTL_HTTP.SET_WALLET(C_WALLET_PATH, null);

        request_contest:=utl_http.create_request_context(
                       wallet_path => C_WALLET_PATH,
                       wallet_password => null,  
                       enable_cookies =>  false,
                       max_cookies => 0,
                       max_cookies_per_site => 0 );    

        HTTP_REQ := utl_http.begin_request(URL,'POST','HTTP/1.1', request_contest);
        UTL_HTTP.SET_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT(HTTP_REQ, 300);  
     ELSE
         HTTP_REQ := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST (URL, 'POST');
     END IF;

     REQ_LENGTH := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(DATA_IN);     

     UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(HTTP_REQ, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
     --UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(HTTP_REQ, 'content-type', 'text/xml');
     UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(HTTP_REQ, 'content-type', 'application/octet-stream');
     --UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(HTTP_REQ, 'content-length', LENGTH(DATA_IN));
     UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(HTTP_REQ, 'content-length', REQ_LENGTH);
     --UTL_HTTP.WRITE_TEXT(HTTP_REQ, DATA_IN);     

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--   Authentication is not required
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--     IF HTTPS THEN
--       UTL_HTTP.SET_AUTHENTICATION(HTTP_REQ, C_AUTH_USER, C_AUTH_PWD);
--       -- UTL_HTTP.SET_AUTHENTICATION(HTTP_REQ, C_AUTH_USER, C_AUTH_PWD, 'Basic', FALSE);
--     END IF;
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
      IF REQ_LENGTH <= 32767   THEN
 
        UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(HTTP_REQ, 'Content-Length', REQ_LENGTH);
        UTL_HTTP.WRITE_RAW(HTTP_REQ, DATA_IN);

      ELSIF REQ_LENGTH >32767 THEN
        UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(HTTP_REQ, 'Transfer-Encoding', 'Chunked');
        WHILE (OFFSET <= REQ_LENGTH)
        LOOP
          DBMS_LOB.READ(DATA_IN, AMOUNT, OFFSET, BUFFER);
          UTL_HTTP.WRITE_RAW(HTTP_REQ, BUFFER);
          OFFSET := OFFSET + AMOUNT;
        END LOOP;
      END IF;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

     HTTP_RESP := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE (HTTP_REQ);

     BEGIN

       LOOP
         UTL_HTTP.READ_TEXT(HTTP_RESP, PIECE);
         DATA_OUT := DATA_OUT || PIECE;
       END LOOP;

       EXCEPTION WHEN UTL_HTTP.END_OF_BODY THEN NULL;

     END;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
--        -- Build a CLOB variable to hold web service response
--        dbms_lob.createtemporary(L_RESPONSE, FALSE );
--        dbms_lob.open( L_RESPONSE, dbms_lob.lob_readwrite );
--
--        BEGIN
--
--            LOOP
--                -- Copy the web service response body
--                -- in a buffer string variable l_buffer
--                UTL_HTTP.READ_TEXT(HTTP_RESP, L_BUFFER);
--                -- Append data from l_buffer to CLOB variable
--                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('buffer2 ->'||L_BUFFER);
--                DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(L_RESPONSE, LENGTH(L_BUFFER), L_BUFFER);
--               
--            END LOOP;
--
--        EXCEPTION  WHEN OTHERS THEN
--            --  Exit loop without exception
--            --  when end-of-body is reached
--            IF SQLCODE <> -29266 THEN
--                RAISE;
--            END IF;
--        END;
--        
        -- Verify the response status and text
        --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Response Status: ' || HTTP_RESP.STATUS_CODE || ' ' || HTTP_RESP.REASON_PHRASE);

        UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(HTTP_RESP) ;
        UTL_HTTP.DESTROY_REQUEST_CONTEXT(request_contest);

 

        RETURN DATA_OUT;

   --     RETURN L_RESPONSE;
 

    EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS
          THEN
 

        RETURN 'SEND FILE ERROR';

    END;
  
  END POST;
```

Thanks in advance

Alessandro